# TypeScript in VS Code: [ts] Cannot file the name console

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I just installed fresh Visual Studio Code 1.23.1 on my MAC and opened a directory with one simple file main.ts (no tsconfig.json there):

```
function getFinalPrice(price: number, discount: number) {
  return price - price/discount;
}

console.log(getFinalPrice(100, 10));
```

The word `console` is underlined with a squiggly red line, and the error reads:

> `[ts] Cannot file the name console".`

I checked the installation directory of VS Code - it has the file `.../extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2016.full.d.ts`, which has this line:

`declare var console: Console;`

Why my VS Code doesn't pick it up?

My colleague tried the same code and he doesn't see this error. The only difference is that I have a freshly installed VS Code. What can be the problem?

**Update:** after adding a simple tsconfig.json file, the error is gone.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": { 
        "noEmitOnError": true, 
        "target": "es5"
    }
  }
```

Is this a must to have tsconfig.json in VS Code projects?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the reason for this error is described in the VS Code docs at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_typescript-files-and-projects

Without the tsconfig.json CS Code works in a File Scope mode and you can only use the code defined within the file, which was not the case with the `console`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `tsconfig.json` file as this will specify the `lib` definitions to include - one of which will contain a definition for `console`.